# Google Chart error: "X values column cannot be of type string"

Tags: php, google-visualization

I am trying to use a google line chart. I can get the `x` and `y` values printed on the page using `echo`, but not in the chart. It gives me the following error:

> "X values column cannot be of type string"

I also closed the while loop after the DataTable but it did not work either.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php

@mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("MYSQL'e Baglanti Yok"); 
@mysql_select_db("exceltosql") or die ("Veritabanina baglanti yapilamadi"); 
$sql1= "SELECT x,y FROM veri  ";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
$result_array = array();
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
$result_array[] = $row1;

echo "<pre>";
echo $row1 ['x'];
echo $row1 ['y'];
}
?>
<html>
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['x', 'y'], 
        ['<?php $row1 ['x'];?>', '<?php $row1 ['y'];?>'],



        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'VO2 vs. VCO2 grafiği',
          hAxis: {title: 'VCO2', minValue: 600, maxValue: 1500},
          vAxis: {title: 'VO2', minValue: 600, maxValue: 1500},
          legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the *actual* generated HTML. How is it *wrong* per the Google Chart documentation (and error message)? Also, nothing to do with the database..

Comment: I checked the HTML source code. It produces DataTable code part as it is needeed (5 times - that is the number of rows in DB) but give this error.

Comment: The error is saying what is wrong. Don't doubt it. It says "Hey, *do not give me strings.*" Look at the generated HTML again - how is it wrong?

Comment: I changed it as below and it worked [<?php $row1 ['x'];?>, <?php $row1 ['y'];?>], but still having problems. Thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of this line:

```
['<?php $row1 ['x'];?>', '<?php $row1 ['y'];?>'],
```

will be something like this:

```
['1', '2'],
```

which encodes your numeric values as a string (as the error message suggests). Removing the extra quotes should do the trick:

```
[<?php $row1 ['x'];?>, <?php $row1 ['y'];?>],
```

Comment: [<?php echo $row1 ['x'];?>, <?php echo $row1 ['y'];?>],
I changed the line as above. It did work but I only get one sctter point. In the source code I point are there but on the graph. On the other hand, In the google example using array they put "," comma after "]" but not on the last one. Since I put tha data on the loop last point also gets "," at the end.

Comment: I think I should use "if" but don't know how  :-). keep trying

Comment: The `,` at the end is not the problem. There is only one scatter-point because you do not loop over the result-set at that point in the code, thus you print only a single (the last) result.

Comment: mmm. I am using while loop and I close it after DataTable. I think that doesn't enough to put tha data in the loop. How can I put them in the loop. Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: OK finally I got it working. I used foreach to put tha data in the loop. Thank you for your help :-)